# RSpec - Testing Strong Parameters ActionController::ParameterMissing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, strong-parameters

How can one test if a certain action raises an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception?

For example:

```
it "raises an exception" do
  post :create, {}
  expect(response).to raise ActionController::ParameterMissing
end
```

The above does not seem to work, it will fail the test with the `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the expect block syntax using the [`raise_error`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-13/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) matcher:

```
it "raises an exception" do
  expect{ post(:create, {}) }.to raise_error ActionController::ParameterMissing
end
```

The reason that your code doesn't work is that `post(:create, {})` raises the exception. This happens before the `expect(response).to ...` code gets executes. Since the `#post` message is not in a `begin...end` block, the raised exception is passed up to RSpec failing the test.

Comment: Great! Can you explain why it works with an expect block but not with the code in the question?

Comment: The exception is raised as part of the call to `post`, not as part of the call to `response`

Comment: Key thing here to note is that the brackets for `except` have changed from `( )` to `{ }`.